# Can I use MeCab on IBM Data Science Experience

Tags: data-science-experience, mecab

I want to use Mecab on IBM Data Science Experience.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mecab-python3

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, or at least not easily. That Python package requires native mecab libraries, which are not installed in the environment where DSX notebooks are running. Neither do users have permission to install them using a package manager (yum).

If you're willing to spend effort, you can try to put the libraries from a mecab rpm into the user file system. Then extend the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include your user directory. Make sure to change the variable using Python's `os.environ`. This will have to be done every time the notebook executes.

Comment: I understood. Thank you very much!