# Unable to run yum command on IBM DSX notebook

Tags: data-science-experience

I am unable to run yum command in DSX environment. I need yum command access to install some packages.

Here's the error I am seeing when I type in "!yum install sox" command in DSX notebook:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible duplicate of this 
[Can I use MeCab on IBM Data Science Experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388310/can-i-use-mecab-on-ibm-data-science-experience/46398330#46398330)

You cannot use yum in DSX Notebook attach to Apache Spark service on Bluemix.

Given Apache Spark service on bluemix does not allow user to install any root level packages which are usually** installed using yum as well.

The only alternative is for you to either try to see if you can download source using !wget or !curl and then try to see if you can compile it, if the package doesn't need any root permission technically , you should be able to compile and install it using make.

You can also raise feature enhancement for getting this package installed by default.
http://ibm.biz/dsxideas

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: It might also be possible to download the rpm containing the compiled binary and extract that into a user location.